# Set scheduling parameters for a pthread in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads, raspbian

I would really like to give the main thread of my program a higher scheduling priority. I tried this with c++11 threads and it fails...

I am using Raspbian Stretch

This was for the main thread:

```
sched_param sch;
int policy;
pthread_getschedparam(pthread_self(), &policy, &sch);
sch.sched_priority = 10;
if (pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_FIFO, &sch)) {
    std::cout << "Failed to setschedparam: " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
}
```

And this for a c++11 thread:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::thread> Stream;
Stream = std::make_unique<std::thread>([&, this]
{
    while (!finished)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2));
        /* more code */
    }
});
sched_param sch;
int policy;
pthread_getschedparam(Stream->native_handle(), &policy, &sch);
sch.sched_priority = 20;
if (pthread_setschedparam(Stream->native_handle(), SCHED_OTHER, &sch))
{
    std::cout << "Failed to setschedparam: " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
}
```

I get `Invalid argument` and I do not understand why...

Best wishes

Comment: When your question **specifically** is about C++, then please stop tagging unrelated languages.

Comment: I thought c was relevant because the called function has nothing to do with c++, but I guess the question is about c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EINVAL is returned if policy is unrecognized/unsupported or param doesn't make sense. SCHED_OTHER makes sense only for threads with priority 0. Behavior you're running into is a typical one for FreeBSD-like systems, they don't ignore `sched_param::priority` non-zero value.

Comment: Ok it worked with 0. What do I need to set the second parameter to if I would like to have a priority of 10 for example?

Comment: @i7clock depends on what kind of ordering and timing you want. SHED_RR or SHED_FIFO are usual choices, you have to read the manual.